# Machine Learning Algorithm Suggestion?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm novice in ML. I've crunch time and in need to choose the algorithm to complete my following task:

Traveler, is visiting my website. I make them fill the form and have all the necessary signal (attributes) with me like whether they have booked flight or not, whether email is genuine is not, phone no is given or not, trip date is fixed, destination location is fixed or not.

But along with that I have many visitor who don't fill the form completely or just uses fake phone number.

I again re-iterate, I have lot of signal available with me, and I need to filter out the traveler who is certain to go for traveling so that I can personally contact them. I also need some score as well on the scale of 10.

Which ML algorithm is best suited for this job and why ?

Previously I have worked in WEKA.

Comment: This is a complex topic, much too broad to answer here. the problem seems to be similar to modeling click-through-rates for online advertisers. Try logistic regression, because it gives you probabilities whether the user will book or not (assuming your words "go for traveling" means "book a trip").

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an ensemble model (composition of many different algorithms).